# Error On Deploying App to Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015, appxmanifest

I recently updated the logo's and app description in the package manifest of my windows 8.1 app. When I deploy the app to a windows phone is shows an error. The building of the app goes perfect with no issues. As soon as it enters deploying to phone and updating layout. It shows the following error. I need help!

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
```

Error       Error : DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: The Appx package's manifest is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080204)    MyNewApp
I also went online and checked for it. I found for the following link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/br211474.aspx
but I didn't quite get where i went wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue. I issue was I didn't load the logo for wide tiles and yet I had checked the option to show name on the wide Tile.